# How to map the url's of view's in browser to one specific name?

Tags: grails, url-mapping

M new to grails n now my problem is,

I want when i browse my application instead of getting URL as ***http://localhost:8080/merchant/*** i want to display only ://localhost.

Like wise when i browse other views of my application i get URL like ***http://localhost:8080/merchant/register/list*** now also i don want it to display app controller and action names there instead i want it to display a single word may be list or something else which i want.

I gone through URLMapping concepts but i din get what exactly to do..I know i should study understand and then ask if any doubt but i don have much time..So please can any one tell me what exactly need to do.

Advance thanks,

Comment: Can any one at least give me a hint as what will work for my problem..please.

Comment: If you don't tag your questions properly, they'll get ignored.  It's up to you.

Comment: Thanks..I will take care of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

actually if you don't have a port in the url it takes the port 80 as default. apache http servers are running on this port normally.

there are two different ways to achieve this for a grails application running on a tomcat server.

- change the port of the tomcat server (use the Dserver.port parameter when you start grails)

> ```
> grails -Dserver.port=80 run-app
> ```

- Or use a apache http server as proxy for your tomcat server.

http://www.unidata.ucar.edu/projects/THREDDS/tech/tds4.1/reference/TomcatBehindProxyServer.html

---

EDIT:

For the second thing with url's. If I get your question right, you want the list view as your default view.
To achieve this, use the following URL Mapping (did not test it though):

```
static mappings = {
    "/$controller" {
       controller = "controller"
       action = "list"
    }
}
```

---

EDIT 2:

You only want to see the action and not the controller name.

- this is only possible for one controller. otherwise how would grails know which action of which controller to use.
- you can define your actions which should be accessible without the controller name in the url in your home controller.

  1. make a home controller
  2. set the following mapping

> ```
> "/$action"
>  {
>     controller = "yourController"
>     action = "action"
>  }
> ```

please be aware this way all index actions on other controllers ex. /controller will not work right, as it expects you have an action with the name controller in your home controller.

---

EDIT 3:
You can also define an url mapping for every action you want to be accessible without controller name in the url. this way the action has not to be in your home controller.

ex

> ```
> "/myAction"
>  {
>     controller = "yourController"
>     action = "myAction"
>  }
> ```

Comment: Thanks -Dserver.port worked for me..with that m not getting tomcat server port in my url.

Comment: but still my problem is not solved..on browse of any of my app's view i want to see only that view name in url not whole url with application/controller/action..with urlmapping how to achieve that.?

Comment: see my edited answer (up-votes for solving the port problem are appreciated) :D

Comment: I don want list view to be default view.My question is just that whenever i brows any view of my application in URl i should be able to see only name of action not like applicationname/controller/action.

Comment: If u still den det my question let me know

Comment: Edited my answer again. But I don't recommend to do this.

Comment: i need to try and check..can i write it in URLmapping file only.or i should create separate homecontroller..

Comment: Nope fore solution edit2 you have to write a home controller. for solution edit3 you can use your existing controllers

Comment: in solution edit3 can i make it for default controller action.

Comment: i want it for my default controller actions too..Sorry but i am really not getting.

Comment: with edit3 solution it works.i should redirect to it through uri..but now another problem is from link also i am calling uri as,<g:linkTo uri:"\list"> now thats is'nt working as it works for redirect.

Comment: static links should work. <a href="/yourAction">. g:link only works right if you use the standard grails urls /controller/action